# React Native .prettierrc.js - coding style documentation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, prettier

When one creates a React Native project with create react native, one gets a `.prettierrc.js` as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  bracketSpacing: false,
  jsxBracketSameLine: true,
  singleQuote: true,
  trailingComma: 'all',
};
```

Where can I find the style guide that matches these settings / the style guide for React Native? Using Google I only found the [Airbnb React/JSX Style Guide](https://airbnb.io/javascript/react) but is this the one matching this config? Isn't there something official directly from Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

There is no style guide specifically for React Native, just like there is no style guide specifically for React.  They are just giving you an opinionated set of fairly common default options.  If you don't like/want these options you can remove/change them.

Here are the docs with all of the prettier options: https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html